# With CQRS, Is it a good desgin to use Kafka for sending commands and make sure aggregates cached locally on one node?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, domain-driven-design, cqrs

With CQRS architecture, in write intensive realtime applications like trading systems, traditional approaches of `loading aggregates from database + distributed cache + distributed lock` do not perform well.

Actor model (AKKA) fits well here but i am looking for an alternative solution. What I have in mind is to use Kafka for sending commands, make use of topic partitioning to make sure commands for the same aggregate always arrive on the same node. Then use `database + local cache + local pessimistic lock` to load aggregate roots and handle commands. This brings 3 main benefits:

1. aggregates are distributed across multiple nodes
2. no network traffics for looking up central cache and distributed locks
3. no serialization  & deserialization  when saving and loading aggregates

One problem of this approach is when consumer groups rebalance, may produce stale aggregate state in the local cache, setting short cache timeouts should work most of time.

Has anyone used this approach in real projects? 
Is it a good design and what are the down sides?
Please share your thoughts and experiences. Thank you.

Comment: Couldn't you flush all cached entities from removed partitions when rebalancing occurs (ConsumerRebalanceListener)? This saves memory and also ensures they are fresh if the partition ever gets re-added to the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Kafka will do the job for you. You need to ensure, if the network is fast enough. 
In our project are reacting on soft real time on customer needs and purchases, and we are sending over Kafka infos to different services, which are performing busines logic. This works well.
Confirmantions on network levels are done well within Kafka broker.
For example when one of Broker nodes crashes, we do not loose messages.

Another matter is if you need any kind of very strong transactional confirmations for all actions, then you need to be careful in design - perhaps you need more topics, to send infos and all needed logical confirmations.
If you need to implement some more logic, like confirmation when the message is processed by other external service, perhaps you will need also disable auto commits.

I do not know if it is complete answer to your question.